# Send Mail via Mail Client

Tags: email, outlook, c++builder, ole

I'm trying to send a filled and "formatted" TMemo via EMail using Outlook.
I used to do this via
`ShellExecuteA(Handle, "OPEN",  "mailto:xx@xx.xx?subject="+ OASubject + "&body="+OMemo->Text, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);`, but the contents of the body have become too large to solve it via mailto.
I plainly didnt get OLE to work, and frankly did not understand much of it.

Do you have any suggestions on how to realize this?
Sending it directly through SMTP isn't an option, since we need to have the user decide from which Mail to send it.

Comment: You can use COM automation to do this directly by automating Outlook. Delphi/C++ Builder come with the COM class wrappers needed to do this if you install the Office automation package that is distributed with them. Use Component->Install Packages and check the box next to the Embarcadero C++ Builder Office XP or Office 2000 package.

Comment: Thanks, I did that and came up with some code, however i get conversion issues. Do you have a code sample of sucha solution?

Comment: nevermind, forgot about c_bstr(). Works now, thanks!!